# Bigquery bitcoin dataset SQL query to obtain transactions after a timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a CSV of all bitcoin transactions after timestamp 1572491526. so i tried below code. I want CSV to have four columns -

```
transaction_id, timestamp, input, output
1                  1        aaa     bbb
1                  1        abc     cde
2                  2        pqr     xyz
```

i tried this so far

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

QUERY =   """
SELECT timestamp, transaction_id, inputs, outputs              
FROM bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions
WHERE timestamp > 1572491526
LIMIT 1

"""



# note that max_gb_scanned is set to 24, rather than 1
queryjob = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = queryjob.result() 

row = list(rows)
import pandas as pd
headlines = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(x.values()) for x in row], columns=list(row[0].keys()))
headlines
```

But the output i am getting is incorrect. how to solve this

```
timestamp   transaction_id  inputs  outputs
0   1237254030000   8425ac5096ff2b55e0feefa7c78ba609a245e6f185ecde...   [{'input_script_bytes': b'\x04\xff\xff\x00\x1d...   [{'output_satoshis': 5000000000, 'output_scrip...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are getting is correct, I tested your query in the Bigquery UI and seems to be the same you are getting. Please consider that the fields **inputs** and **outputs** are arrays, the confusion might be there.

[image]

Also, I tested your code and I got the same output

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
QUERY =   """
SELECT timestamp, transaction_id, inputs, outputs              
FROM bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions
WHERE timestamp > 1572491526
LIMIT 1
"""
# note that max_gb_scanned is set to 24, rather than 1
queryjob = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = queryjob.result() 
row = list(rows)
import pandas as pd
headlines = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(x.values()) for x in row], columns=list(row[0].keys()))
headlines.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

[image]